# Combination or rewriting rules for complex redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a fair knowledge of rewriting in .htaccess, but this problem really has me beaten.

I recently re-created my listing website on Wordpress and now need to set up a number of 301 redirects in htaccess to ensure that any indexed pages are not lost. The problem is that the **old website** used a domain / directory structure as follows:

- /
- /blog/
- /contact/
- /listingname1/
- /listingname2/
- /listingname3/
- ...
- /listingname1999/

Where 'listingname' could be anything like 'toms-hardware' or 'the-bakery' etc.

The **new website** is on Wordpress and uses a listing Theme where the domain and the domain / directory structure is as follows:

- /
- /blog/
- /contact/
- /my/listing/listingname1/
- /my/listing/listingname2/
- /my/listing/listingname3/
- ...
- /my/listing/listingname1999/

In a nutshell the root remain the same for both sites as do the blog and contact pages (and one or two other main pages). However, each of the listing pages redirects to a  directory/listing page as shown above. Normally this would be straightforward but as the source listing URL is off the root in the old site and as there is no pattern to identify the listing name; and as there are so many listings this has to be done using a regex pattern of some sort for these items in the root. The rules have to work on excluding everything that is does not change and then redirect everything else from the root to the new listing directory structure.

I have tried a number of different approaches to map the old to the new, but they just won't work for everything. Here is what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/my/listing/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I think maybe I don't understand the use of RewriteCond when there is a not (!) criterion. If anyone can help and show where I have gone wrong or add any suggestions, this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem is to use the start and end regex characters to define exactly the part of the URI you want to target. Here is a step through on what you may need:

Switch on the Rewrite Engine and set the DocumentRoot as the path for relative URL's:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Exclude the root directory so that the home page continues to work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
```

As you are using Wordpress, exclude any admin/dashboard pages

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/.*$ [NC]
```

Exclude the Blog page

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$ [NC]
```

Now the key rewrite condition - check if there are any pages with a single directory name and nothing after this (notice the use of the start '^' and end '$' regex characters) and the regex to select one or more alphanumeric characters and '-' or '_'.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/$ [NC]
```

This criterion will be true for https://example.com/listingname1/ but not for https://example.com/listingname1/abc.

Finally define the RewriteRule as

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/$ https://example.com/my/listing/$1/ [L,R]
```

A few points to be aware of, there is no '/' at the start of the RewriteRule and you do not need a condition to exclude the 'my/listing' pages because these fail condition #5 and therefor will not be redirected.

Putting it all together:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/$ https://example.com/my/listing/$1/ [L,R]
```

If you have other single directory pages that you want to exclude (and it is likely that there will be others), include these as Rewrite Conditions as follows:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other/.*$ [NC]
```

Also remember not to include the [R=301] rewrite flag during testing because your browser will cache the result and you will need to keep clearing the browser cache between tests. I suggest that you just use [R] until you have tested that the rules work and then add the '=301' just before you go-live.

Comment: Thank you - worked perfectly for me! Thank you also for the wonderful tip about leaving the 301 redirect definition until the last minute.